# Delete/Filter rows based on the dplyr groupby output

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Suppose I have a dataframe as follows,

```
ID <- c("A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C") 
Type <- c(45,46,47,45,46,47,45,46)
Point_A <- c(10,15,20,8,9,10,35,33) 
df <- data.frame(ID,Type,Point_A)
```

I am using a dplyr groupby function to this dataframe,

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise(q=n())
```

The following is the output I am getting,

```
      ID     q
  (fctr) (int)
1      A     3
2      B     3
3      C     2
```

Now I want to filter the rows that have count of 2. Ideally the code should remove, the rows that are behind the count of 2. The output of the code should be,

```
  ID Type Point_A
1  A   45      10
2  A   46      15
3  A   47      20
4  B   45       8
5  B   46       9
6  B   47      10
```

Because the rows that gave count of 2 has been removed.

Is it possible to do this? Can anybody help me in doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `n()` and `filter()` together without `summarize()`:

```
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(n() != 2)

# Source: local data frame [6 x 3]
# Groups: ID [2]
# 
#       ID  Type Point_A
#   (fctr) (dbl)   (dbl)
# 1      A    45      10
# 2      A    46      15
# 3      A    47      20
# 4      B    45       8
# 5      B    46       9
# 6      B    47      10
```

Comment: Thanks.. It's of a great help. Not able to accept the answer now. Will do it in 10 mins